# How to use a php value in wordpress do shortcode function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a meta box in my custom post type that will return a shortcode like `[jwp-video n="1"]`
so I want to display my `shortcode in my theme`. (here is showing video using jw player). I get the `metabox` value this way:

```html
<?php
$value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'metabox_id', true );
?>
```

and I know this function:

```html
<?php
<?php echo do_shortcode("[shortcode]"); ?>
?>
```

but how can I use my $value in this function to display `shortcode`?

Comment: Which function do you want to use this shortcode?

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question exactly, ideally you would give us the whole function you are using to have a better understanding.  But if the meta value contains the shortcode you can do the following:
`<?php
$value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'metabox_id', true );
echo do_shortcode($value);
?>`

Comment: i use this, but the short code wont display at all

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix use this but this text display not my video : [jwp-video n='1']

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix `$vaule` is `[jwp-video n="1"]` like I said and it display a video. I want to do this short code but with different values that I get from my metabox

Comment: No this is what you said `use this but this text display not my video : [jwp-video n='1']` which is quite different then `$value = [jwp-video n='1']`.  What do you mean with `with different values`  if `$value = [jwp-video n='1']` or does values in this instance mean  just `n=?`  See you have to be specific.

Comment: Why dont you do `do_shortcode("[jwp-video n='{$var}']");` where `$var` are these "other" values

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix is right. It's better to go this way. But if you insist, you must do a regular expression replace: `preg_replace`

Comment: Elyas, please update your question (just click **[edit]**) instead of adding new info here on comments...

Answer (score 0):

Did you register shortcode?

```
add_shortcode('your_shortcode', 'callback_function');
```